# What are the rules for who wins when the gold is reached in Saboteur 2?

Tags: saboteur-2

In Saboteur 2, I am having trouble understanding precisely which dwarves win in certain situations. Could someone clarify what's already in the rulebook?

In particular, I was wondering: if a dwarf from the green team reaches the gold, does the blue team also win (and vice-versa)?

The way that made the most sense in my head was: if any dwarf of ANY kind reaches the gold, then winners include: the boss, the profiteer, and dwarves on teams for which a path to the gold is NOT blocked by a door. However, the rules seemed to say that WHICH dwarf reached the gold actually mattered, which doesn't really seem sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree the the rules are poorly phrased in the "A team wins if:" section.  It provides an outcome tree, but clearly fails to provide a branch for what happens if a dwarf from the other team creates a connection to the treasure, and the way is not blocked for that team by a door of the wrong colour.

Later in the rules, under "Splitting The Treasure" it states:

> Depending on whether there is an uninterrupted path from the start to
>   the treasure or not, the Gold-Diggers or the Saboteurs win the round.
>   If the path to the treasure is blocked by a door, only the dwarves
>   from the team of the same color win.

I think from that paragraph it becomes pretty clear that an uninterrupted path unblocked by any door would be a victory for all Gold-Diggers.  I think your initial instincts were right and you shouldn't worry too much about the sloppily-phrased earlier paragraph.  These things do happen, much to the distress of OCD rules lawyers like us!

Comment: FWIW, while this answer _could be_ right, I don't really find the reasoning presented in it particularly convincing. I've asked [a separate question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45346/apparent-contradiction-in-the-saboteur-2-rules-does-it-matter-which-team-finds) about whether there are any errata or other official sources that would explicitly state which interpretation of the rules is the intended one.

Answer (score 0):

The green team wins because they reached the end, played the last connection. The blue team does not win in your scenario.

Though I still don't understand how many gold to distribute myself. I do know the above.

Comment: This seems to have been responding to the other answer, but answers need to address the question itself - we're a Q&A site, and we don't work like a forum or do post-to-post discussion. See our [tour] for more information. I recommend if you want to back this up with a citation (e.g. the description you mentioned), you quote what you're citing.